# How to solve build error - Package modules may not define LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX

Tags: android, android-source

I am building an AOSP version for the first time and trying to put my application as a system app. So i made this android.mk file but during during build process, it is giving out error - Package modules may not define LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX. Can please someone help me out.
Alternatives to this method are also welcome, i just need to install my application as system app so that it gets more permissions.
My android.mk file is :-

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := CallRecorder_static
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, java)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR = $(LOCAL_PATH)/res
include $(BUILD_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARY)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := CallRecorder
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled 
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_APPS)
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libarity android-support-v4  
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Comment: Why did you add `include $(BUILD_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARY)` line in your Android.mk?
Do you want to build a `.jar` as well? If yes, is that `.jar` being used by your system app?
If you do not want a `.jar` and just need the system app `.apk`, then remove `LOCAL_MODULE` line and `include $(BUILD_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARY)` line from the Android.mk.

Comment: This is a good reference on how to build Android system apps : https://android.jlelse.eu/system-app-in-android-f003d418b4cc .
Author has mentioned that `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` is mandatory to add in `AndroidManifest.xml`, but it is not. It is being [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid) in android-29. You can skip that. But the rest is fine.

Comment: I have also referred the same article and trust me i did everything in same manner but build gave errors. I took suggestions from the build errors and added lines in android.mk. Later i got this error and got stuck. I googled it and found no solution.